# Security Key store into constant file is secure or suggest any alternate solution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, keychain

I am using `AWS` services to post my images and `SNS` services for push notification in it.
To post images on the `AWS` server I have the `secret key` & `access key` with me currently I am using that key from the Constant file which is a very simple and easy way to access any defined key.

```
#define AWS_AccessKey               @"###############"
#define AWS_SecretKey               @"####################"
```

But what my question is

**is this key secure from others?**

**is anyone can get easily from Constant file? if YES how ?**

Also, I have one more key of my encrypted database of `SQLCypher` so that key is also stored in my Constant file.

```
#define DB_KEY             @"####################"
```

What is the best way to store our important keys? and where?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are better ways depending on the environment. where is the application running? ec2?

Comment: yes its on ec2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have investigated more in the above `secret key` store concern I found my solution as mention below.

Reference question to `AWS` for security key link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63089

As per the above link, `AWS` suggests that we need to implement **TVM (Token Vending Machine)** based service calling to give special rights to user to upload data on `S3` or upload data on `S3` with a particular `bucket`.

TVM is a kind of token service that gives user Token valid for `12 hours` to `36 hours` (**max**) to communicate with the server.

if Token expires it will again call the service and get a new token from `AWS`.

The temporary credentials provided by `AWS` Security Token Service consist of four components:

- Access key
- ID Secret
- access key
- Session token
- Expiration time

The source for the TVMs is available at GitHub for both the Anonymous TVM and the Identity TVM. By this example, we can get how to get `TVM` and how to use it to communicate with the server.

**Anonymous TVM:** https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-tvm-anonymous

**Identity TVM:** https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-tvm-identity

Hope this will help others who all struggling with the same security issue for storing secret key.

Full Link for AWS secret key storing: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Mobile/4611615499399490

Answer (score 2):

Since the app runs on ec2 a more secure way would be to use an IAM Role attached to the instance. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

That way you wont have to store the AWS keys anywhere. For your SQLCypher key you could use the user data script to pass the key to your ec2 instance at first boot and store it there, so you wont have to store that in the code at least.
Generally such config is best kept in the [environment](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: I didn't get `environment` detail means not able to understand how to use `config` file in iOS app can you please explain this ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the Key in EC2 user-data. From the User Guide: *Although you can only access instance metadata and user data from within the instance itself, the data is not protected by cryptographic methods. Anyone who can access the instance can view its metadata. Therefore, you should take suitable precautions to protect sensitive data (such as long-lived encryption keys). You should not store sensitive data, such as passwords, as user data.*  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the best way to use AWS services from EC2 without needing long-term credentials is to assign an IAM Role to the instance (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

If security is critical for you, I suggest to store the SQLCypher key in [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/). KMS can then be accessed by your EC2 instance using its IAM Role.